# I'm trying to create a text-based game where you have to avoid a monster while collecting Items

Tags: python

The code for the rooms works but changing the rooms doesn't the code also loops to the start even when the required part to move on is obtained. The game over will be put in along with the code for the monster's movements so that when the monster and the player are in the same room the game ends in a game over. The monster's movements are going to be random so game-overs will be random.

```
    'Entrance Hall': {'name': 'Entrance Hall', 'exits': {'North': 'Great Hall', 'West': 'Bathroom'}},
    'Great Hall': {'name': 'Great Hall', 'exits': {'West': 'Bedroom', 'East': 'Kitchen', 'North': 'Throne Room',
                                                   'South': 'Entance Hall'}},
    'Bedroom': {'name': 'Bedroom', 'exits': {'North': 'Great Hall', 'East': 'Cellar', 'West': 'Bathroom'}},
    'Cellar': {'name': 'Cellar', 'exits': {'West': 'Bedroom'}},
    'Attic': {'name': 'Attice', 'exits': {'South': 'Throne Room'}},
    'Kitchen': {'name': 'Kitchen', 'exits': {'North': 'Celler', 'West': 'Great Hall'}},
    'Bathroom': {'name': 'Bathroom', 'exits': {'East': 'Bedroom', 'North': 'Entarnce Hall'}},
    'Throne Room': {'name': 'Throne Room', 'exits': {'South': 'Great Hall', 'North': 'Attic'}},
}

def game():
    """starts the game"""
    game_over = False
    quit = False
    answer = input('Start game? y/n?')
    if answer.lower() == 'y':
        print('Welcome to a world of unknown creatures and mazes')
        print('You wake up in the Entrance hall of an Abandoned Castle')
        current_room = rooms['Entrance Hall']
        inventory = []
        while current_room == rooms['Entrance Hall']:
            print(current_room)
            print('You see two doors one has an ornate gold trim around it the other is plain')
            print('the door with the ornate trim leads to the Great Hall')
            print('The other door leads to the bathroom')
            answer = input('Which room do you want to check out first?')
            if answer.lower() == 'Bathroom':#to change the current room to the bathroom
                current_room = rooms['Bathroom']
                print(current_room)
                break
            elif answer.lower() == 'Great Hall':#same as above but for the great hall
                current_room = rooms['Great Hall']
                break
            elif answer.lower() == 'q' or 'Quit':#first idea for the quit
                pass
        while current_room == rooms['Bathroom']:
            print(current_room)
            if 'Key Fragment 1' is not in inventory:
                print('You see the shine of an object')
                answer = input('do you want to inspect it? Yes? No?')
                if answer.lower() == 'yes' or 'y':
                    print('its a key fragment')
                    answer = input('Do you take it? Yes? No?')
                    if answer.lower() == 'yes' or 'y':
                        print('You have taken the key fragment')
                        inventory.append('Key Fragment 1')
                        print(inventory)
                    else:
                        print('You left the key fragment)
                else:
                    print('You decided to leave the mysterious object alone')
            while 'Key fragment 1' in inventory:
                print('There are two doors')
                print('The first is the door to the Entrance Hall')
                print('The other goes to a Bedroom')
                pass
    else:
        print('Maybe later')


game()
```

while I can get some of the code to work I cannot get the game to change from the Entrance Hall to the other rooms then I need to make a quit command. I'm just learning Python and the book hasn't helped me much. While testing the code it kept looping one part and would force the yes answer even when the no answer is typed. The initial input works fine but the rest doesn't. no problems show on the debug screen and it doesn't crash on me. What would be the best way to fix the code so it works but doesn't loop or force answers? Also, what would be the best way to add the other rooms to the code so that when the item in the room is collected it allows for movement to other rooms. Finally, I need help with the code to end the game once all the items are collected.

Comment: Questions on Stack Overflow should focus on a single technical problem you're having with your code. You've asked several here; as such it's difficult to parse out which question *exactly* you need assistance with. [ask]

Comment: "*What would be the best way to fix the code so it works but doesn't loop or force answers?*" "*Also, what would be the best way to add the other rooms to the code so that when the item in the room is collected it allows for movement to other rooms.*" The "*best way*" to do *anything* is inherently subjective, questions of which type are explicitly off-topic per the scope of the site defined in the [help/on-topic].

Comment: My main issue is the movement system

Comment: Can you edit your question such that it focuses on that question *only* and includes only the code necessary to reproduce whatever issue it is that you're having in accordance with our guidance on creating a [mre], as well as [ask]?

Comment: `rooms` isn't defined so I can't run your code to see what's wrong with it.

Comment: I added the rooms

Comment: It looks like you copied part of this code out of the book without understanding what it's supposed to be for.  Is there an earlier lesson you could start with?  This is a fairly complex project for someone who's still working on learning the basics.

Comment: I am still learning but I didn't copy any code from and even with the book I learn more from trial and error and simple explinations

Comment: @davidboyer I'm referring to the `rooms` dict, which was very clearly provided as part of the assignment, but your code indicates that you don't understand how it's supposed to be used.  Again, I'd suggest starting with one of the introductory assignments instead of skipping ahead.  It's hard to give a simple explanation when the code is complex and there are a lot of things wrong with it.

Comment: @Samwise I understand what you mean but I'm still learning Python and only have about 10 hours working with it as the book has very little in text and more so here's a problem solve it.

Comment: If this particular book throws you into the deep end, you should start with a book or tutorial that's aimed at beginners.  https://www.python.org/about/gettingstarted/

Answer (score 1):

The method `str.lower()`, which you are calling in the branch checks returns strings converted to lowercase, so all of the checks you are using to change rooms will always be `false`. Try replacing

```py
if answer.lower() == 'Bathroom'
```

with

```py
if answer.lower() == 'bathroom'
```

and so on.